# Apache Camel Integration test results in OutOfMemory

Tags: spring-mvc, apache-camel, spock, spring-java-config, spring-test-mvc

I have a simple Camel route that sends data to an external REST interface, integrated with Spring MVC.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private camelService camelService;

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value = "/test")
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    public TestModel createEV(@Valid @RequestBody TestModel testModel) {
       camelService.publishTestCase(testModel);
       return testModel;
    }
}

@Service
public class CamelService {

    @Produce(uri = "direct:test")
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    @Override
    public void publishTestCase(TestModel testModel) {
        producerTemplate.sendBody(testModel);
    }
}

@Component
public class TestRouter extends SpringRouteBuilder 

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {

        errorHandler(loggingErrorHandler(log).level(LoggingLevel.ERROR));

        from("direct:test")
            .routeId("testRoute")
            .beanRef("mapper", "map")
            .to("velocity:test.vm")
            .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, simple("POST"))
            .to("log:test?level=DEBUG&showAll=true&multiline=true&maxChars=100000")
            .to("cxfrs:http://url.here");
    }
}
```

Then there's an integration test for the rest endpoint with mockMvc that mocks the external camel endpoint.

```
@ContextConfiguration(loader = SpringApplicationContextLoader, classes = Application)
@WebIntegrationTest
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
class MyControllerIntegrationTest extends Specification {

    @Autowired
    private CamelContext camelContext

    MockMvc mockMvc

    @Autowired
    WebApplicationContext wac

    @Shared
    def setupOnceRun = false

    @Shared
    def validInput = new File(JSON_DIR + '/valid.json').text

    def setup() {
        mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build()
        // no way to use setupSpec as Autowired fields can't be Shared
        if (!setupOnceRun) {
            ModelCamelContext mcc = camelContext.adapt(ModelCamelContext);
            camelContext.getRouteDefinition("testRoute).adviceWith(mcc, new AdviceWithRouteBuilder() {
                @Override
                public void configure() throws Exception {
                    mockEndpointsAndSkip("cxfrs:http://url.here")
                }
            });
            setupOnceRun = true
        }
    }

    def 'valid scenario'() {
        setup:
          MockEndpoint mockEndpoint = (MockEndpoint) camelContext.hasEndpoint("mock:cxfrs:http://url.here")
          mockEndpoint.expectedMessageCount(1)
        when:
          def response = mockMvc.perform(post('/test').content(validInput)).andReturn()
        then:
          response.getResponse().getStatus() == 201
          mockEndpoint.assertIsSatisfied()
    }
}
```

The test is passing if you run it by itself but once it's included in the build together with other integration tests it's constantly producing OutOfMemory. MaxPermSize is 4G, it doesn't look like that's an issue. I am new to Camel so my guess is that I am wiring the test in a wrong way. Would appreciate any suggestions.